# Checkstyle rules for Google Java Style

Tags: java, coding-style, checkstyle

Is there a Checkstyle rule file with the [Google Java Style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html)?

Comment: Perhaps you could try out Google's [error-prone](https://code.google.com/p/error-prone/), or [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), which they also contributed to.

Answer (score 20):

The checkstyle team added it several days ago. Here it is : 
https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Comment: As of writing, the URL has changed to https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Answer (score 13):

If you have a maven-project, you can easily integrate google_checks (you have to use at least `maven-checkstyle-plugin` version 2.17)

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.17</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Executing checkstyle will use google_checks, e.g. do

```
mvn checkstyle:checkstyle
```

**Version-background**

Checkstyle-project integrates google_checks from [version 6.9](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.9%20%22Checkstyle%206.%229%20release%20notes) on.
Maven-checkstyle-plugin version 2.17. is the first one, which is released after checkstyle6.9 (actually it uses [checkstyle6.11.2](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/history.html)). So, maven-checkstyle-plugin2.17 is the first version of this plugin, which actually ships with google_checks and provides it without any other dependency.

Comment: If I'm not using maven where can I get that version of `google_checks`? The one at github uses the snapshot version of check style

Comment: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Answer (score 3):

The [Google Summer of Code project](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/wiki/Checkstyle-GSoC-2014-Project-Ideas#project-name-checkstyle-configuration-for-googles-java-style-guide) to create such a file implies, that it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to check version of checkstyle in `build.gradle`:

```
println checkstyle.toolVersion
```

I believe that you've already added:

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
}
```

After that try to find appropriate version of checkstyle in [checkstyle releases](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/releases).

Download release and unpack only file `/src/main/resources/google_check.xml`

Put `google_check.xml` to your project in `./config/checkstyle/` (it's default folder)

Configure checkstyle in `build.gradle`:

```
checkstyle {
    configFile file("config/checkstyle/google_checks.xml")
}
checkstyleMain {
    source = 'src/main/java'
}
checkstyleTest {
    source = 'src/test/java'
}
```

Worked for gradle 8.4, checkstyle 9.3, Java 17.

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

google_checks.xml comes with Checkstyle and the maven plugin.
See [Google's Java Style Checkstyle Coverage](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/google_style.html),
also see [Maven Checkstyle Plugin's config](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html)

Note that if you are going to customize the config based on google_checks.xml, you need to download the xml of the matching checkstyle version (on github), and modify on top of it.