# Java google checkstyle Maven

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I'm trying to configure my Maven project to use google java check style with the following configuration:

google_checks.xml: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

pom.xml

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>checkstyle</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <configuration>
        <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
        <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
        <enableFilesSummary>false</enableFilesSummary>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

It seems to run `mvn checkstyle:check` fine at first. But after a few runs I start getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check 
(default-cli) on project PROJECT: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize 
module TreeWalker - Token "METHOD_REF" was not found in Acceptable tokens list in check 
com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.SeparatorWrapCheck -> [Help 1]
```

What does that mean? Why does it only happen some times and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: You probably need to configure a newer version of Checkstyle as described here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html .
The maven-checkstyle-plugin uses Version 6.11.2 by default which might not have all rules used in the google checks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Token "METHOD_REF" was not found in Acceptable tokens list in check 
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.SeparatorWrapCheck

You are trying to use a newer configuration with an old version of Checkstyle.

The configuration at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml is in `master` which is dependent on the snapshot version of checkstyle.

If you are using google configuration without any modifications, you need to use the one that comes embedded in checkstyle. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486365/1016482

Otherwise you can integrate a newer version of checkstyle to work with maven. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27359107/1016482

Comment: If I'm not using maven, how can I get it?

Comment: @moondaisy Checkstyle has the google configuration embeded into it. That can be accessed via command line, maven, etc. You can also extract it from the JAR and place it as a file on your HD if you need to. It all depends on how you are invoking Checkstyle. If you need specifics for your setup, you may want to start a new question.

Comment: I looked it up in the jar and it doesn't seem to be there, I'm using the Check Style plugin for NetBeans so I need the file separately.

Comment: @moondaisy It is probably best you open your own question and tag Checkstyle since it is specific to NetBeans plugin.

Answer (score 10):

I was using version 3.0.0 (which is the newest one right now) of the maven-checkstyle-plugin and I still got the error. I solved it by adding the following dependency to the plugin.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
     <version>8.11</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Maven-checkstyle-plugin by default uses Checkstyle 6.18 and they haven't changed it since it would require Java 7+ for their project.