# Google Checks for Netbeans Checkstyle plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, checkstyle

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 and the [google_checks.xml](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) file to configure CheckStyle

This is the error that Netbeans is showing:

[image]

It seems to be this part of the file:

```
<module name="SeparatorWrap">
    <property name="id" value="SeparatorWrapMethodRef"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_REF"/>
    <property name="option" value="nl"/>
</module>
```

But according to the [doc](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#SeparatorWrap) it is a valid value.

How can I fix this?

### **Update**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060396/3695939) the problem is that the `google_checks.xml` I downloaded is using a newer configuration of Checkstyle.

I'm using the [Checkstyle Netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3413/checkstyle-beans) plugin version 8.1, where can I find the correct `google_checks.xml` file for that version? I tried downloading the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` jar from Maven and looking for the file in there but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found out, the root cause of your problem is that the version of the configuration file does not match the version of Checkstyle you are using.
So, you must find out the Checkstyle version and download the matching configuration file.

Afaik, for Checkstyle Beans, the only way to find out the tool version is by looking inside the plugin file. The most recent version of Checkstyle Beans is 4.1.0 (8.2 is the NetBeans IDE version it seems).

- Inside the [binary distribution](https://www.sickboy.cz/repository/cz/sickboy/netbeans-checkstyle/) of the plugin, there is a file called *netbeans-checkstyle-library-4.6.15.nbm*.
- Rename to `.zip` and open
- Inside, go to the folder *netbeans\modules\autoload\ext*
- In that folder, you find the Checkstyle jar with its version. In this case, the Checkstyle version is **6.15**.

The matching file may be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/checkstyle-6.15/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml). Note the version number in the URL. You can modify it to get the matching file for other versions.

This is a bit complicated, but you only need to do it once for each new version of Checkstyle Beans, which does not seem to be very often. ;-) Hope this helps!